# Update data in form. Stay editable. (React with Redux, sans redux-form)

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### Problem

[image]

I have a list of people. I want to:

1. Select a user to edit by clicking on their name.
2. Edit that user's information, so I can click the submit button and update the list.
3. If I click on a different name, I want to switch to that person's information without having to deliberately close the form first.

[image]

Everything works until #3. When I click on another person, the form, itself, does NOT update.

### My Code

*Update Component* for the update form:

```
const UpdateForm = ({ updatePerson, personToUpdate, handleInputChange }) => {

  let _name, _city, _age, _id;

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    updatePerson({
      name: _name.value,
      city: _city.value,
      age: _age.value,
      _id: _id.value
    });

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <h3>Update Person</h3>
        <label htmlFor="_id">Some Unique ID: </label>
        <input type="text" name="_id" ref={input => _id = input}  id="_id" defaultValue={personToUpdate._id} onChange={input => handleInputChange(personToUpdate)} required />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ref={input => _name = input} id="name" defaultValue={personToUpdate.name} onChange={input => handleInputChange(personToUpdate)} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="city">City: </label>
        <input type="text" name="city" ref={input => _city = input} id="city" defaultValue={personToUpdate.city} onChange={input => handleInputChange(personToUpdate)} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age: </label>
        <input type="text" name="age" ref={input => _age = input} id="age" defaultValue={personToUpdate.age} onChange={input => handleInputChange(personToUpdate)} />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>

    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdateForm;
```

Relevant parts of *Person Component*:

```
class Person extends Component {

  nameClick() {
    if (this.props.person._id !== this.props.personToUpdate._id) {
      this.props.setForUpdate(this.props.person);
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
    else {
      this.props.toggleUpdatePersonPanel();
    }

  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <span onClick={this.nameClick}>
                {this.props.person.name} ({this.props.person.age})
            </span>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Person;
```

Relevant parts of *PeopleList*, which holds Persons:

```
class PeopleList extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.people.map((person) => {
          return <Person
            key={person._id}
            person={person}
            updatePersonPanel={this.props.updatePersonPanel}
            setForUpdate={this.props.setForUpdate}
            personToUpdate={this.props.personToUpdate}
            />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

} // end class

export default PeopleList;
```

*Form Reducer*, with just the relevant actions:

```
export default function formReducer(state = initialState.form, action) {
  let filteredPeople;

  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_UPDATE_PANEL:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { updatePersonPanel: false }, { personToUpdate: {
        _id: "",
        name: "",
        city: "",
        age: ""
      }});
    case SET_FOR_UPDATE:            
      return Object.assign({}, state, { personToUpdate: action.person }, { updatePersonPanel: true });
    case UPDATE_RECORD:
      filteredPeople = state.people.filter((person) => {
        return person._id === action.person._id ? false : true;
      }); // end filter

      return Object.assign({}, state, { people: [ ...filteredPeople, action.person] }, { personToUpdate: {
        _id: "",
        name: "",
        city: "",
        age: ""
      }}, { updatePersonPanel: false });
    case HANDLE_INPUT_CHANGE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { personToUpdate: action.person });
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

The relevant parts of my Initial State file:

```
  form: {
    people: [
      {
        _id: "adfpnu64",
        name: "Johnny",
        city: "Bobville",
        age: 22
      },
      {
        _id: "adf2pnu6",
        name: "Renee",
        city: "Juro",
        age: 21
      },
      {
        _id: "ad3fpnu",
        name: "Lipstasch",
        city: "Bobville",
        age: 45
      }
    ],
    updatePersonPanel: false,
    personToUpdate: {
      _id: "",
      name: "",
      city: "",
      age: ""
    },
  }
```

### Attempts at a Solution( so far)

- I have attempted to make the component a completely controlled component, by switching the form attribute to `value` instead of `defaultValue`. When I do this, the names switch just fine, but the form becomes unchangeable and useless.

### My Questions

Almost all of the solutions to these kind of issues either recommend using redux-form or supply [two-way binding solutions that work fine in React without reduce](https://medium.com/@thejenniekim/two-way-data-binding-and-form-validation-in-react-9d0b15123176). **I want to know how to do this with Redux without using redux-form or anything extra if possible.** Is there a way to resolve this without touching lifecycle methods?

### Conclusion (For now)

Well, for now, I settled for making my form uncontrolled and used some classic Js DOM methods and a lifecycle method to control the form. For whatever reason, once I employed some of the answer suggestions my browser ate up my CPU and crashed, presumably because there was some kind of infinite loop. If anyone has some further recommendations, I'd really appreciate it. For now I settle for this:

```
class UpdateForm extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.personToUpdate._id !== this.props.personToUpdate._id) {
      document.getElementById("name").value = nextProps.personToUpdate.name;
      document.getElementById("age").value = nextProps.personToUpdate.age;
      document.getElementById("city").value = nextProps.personToUpdate.city;
    }

  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.updatePerson({
      name: document.getElementById("name").value,
      city: document.getElementById("city").value,
      age: document.getElementById("age").value,
      _id: this.props.personToUpdate._id
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <h3>Update Person</h3>
          Unique ID: {this.props.personToUpdate._id}
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" ref="name" defaultValue={this.props.personToUpdate.name} required />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="city">City: </label>
          <input type="text" name="city" id="city" ref="city" defaultValue={this.props.personToUpdate.city} required />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="age">Age: </label>
          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" ref="age" defaultValue={this.props.personToUpdate.age} required />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
} // end class

export default UpdateForm;
```

I'll be soon exploring `redux-form` because it is evident that forms as inputs and outputs are a wonky business. For now, my little app works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and you are on the right path. The way is to use `value` instead of `defaultValue` but you have to read the `value` from a state and then use the `onChange` handler to modify the state.

Something like

```
this.state = {inputText:''}
```

Then in the input field

```
<input value={this.state.inputText} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

And the `handleChange` function will be

```
handleChange(event){
   this.setState({inputText:event.target.value})
}
```

Remember to bind the `handleChange` event in the constructor so you can pass it as `this.handleChange` in the input field's `onChange` prop.

Something like this

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html - Here are the official docs regarding it

Also if you want to do it in `redux` the same sort of logic applies where this will be the input field

```
<input value={this.props.inputText} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
```

where `inputText` and `handleChange` are redux state and action respectively passed to the component via `props`

For your case I guess it has to be something like where you are 'reading' values from the `people` array and the `action` bound to the `onChange` modifies that value in the `people` array in the `state`.

<--EDIT-->

How it can be done for the case in point. Pass the `people` in the redux state as a `people` prop to the component. Pass an action `changePeople(newPeople)` to the component as a prop which takes an argument `newPeople` and changes the `people` in the redux state to have the value `newPeople`. Since `people` is nested in `form` you'll have to do some `Object.assign` etc to modify the state.

Now in the component using the `people` props populate the checkboxes using a `map` function. The `map` function takes a second parameter `index` so for each checkbox have a function which sets the local state variable `currentPerson` to the value of the `index`

```
this.props.people.map((person,index) => 
    return <Checkbox onClick={()=>this.setState(currentPerson:index)}/>
)
```

So everytime you click on a checkbox the `currentPerson` points to the corresponding `index`.

Now the input fields can be

```
<input value={this.props.people[this.state.currentPerson].name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'name')}/>
```

This is for the 'name' input field. It reads from the `currentPerson` index of the `people` array which has been passed down as a `prop`.

This is how the `handleChange` will be like

```
handleChange(property,event){
  const newPeople = [
                    ...this.props.people.slice(0, this.state.currentPerson),
                    Object.assign({}, this.props.people[this.state.currentPerson], {
                        [property]: event.target.value
                    }),
                    ...this.props.people.slice(this.state.currentPerson + 1)
                    ]

  this.props.changePeople(newPeople)

}
```

The `handleChange` takes a property (so you don't have to write separate handlers for each input field). The `newPeople` basically modifies the element at current index `this.state.currentPerson` in the `people` passed from `props` (ES6 syntax being used here. If you have doubts do ask). Then it is dispatched using the `changePeople` action which was also passed as props.

Comment: I *feel* like I tried all that before, but I'm going to take these suggestions and REALLY make sure. I'll report back asap.

Comment: Do you know... Can this.props.inputText be on an object, such as this.props.inputTextObject.nameInput or would that be too deep for react to diff?

Comment: Yes it can be. Since `people` is an array when you are creating the checkboxes maybe map it from the people array so that each checkbox when clicked makes the `currentUser` (a part of the component state) be equal to the `index` of the array.

And then it could be something like
`<input value={this.props.people[index].name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'name')}/>`

So now as the index changes the values in the inputs keep changing.

And the `handleChange` can dispatch the action and keep change the original `people` in the redux `state`. I'll add in the original answer.

Comment: Progress! What I learned about how to apply Function.prototype.bind today was worth 100 up votes. I have it working, but... If I actually make it a fully controlled component and update a value on my state for every change, I get a range error. It crashes the browser window in an infinite loop.

Comment: The code example I gave updates the state on every keystroke which I believe is not exactly what you desire. Why not stash all the changes in a local `state` variable (in the component) and dispatch only while pressing Submit. And if there's a cancel button make the local `state` equal to the redux `state`. This way you'll minimize the number of dispatches in redux by a long shot. But even then there shouldn't be a range error.

Comment: But if every time I update the form, it updates the data, and every time the data updates the form updates... Doesn't this cause an infinite loop? ...Isn't this the way it is with controlled components?

Comment: React does a render everytime the state changes. So when you press a key, the state changes and a rerender happens with the new state. Then it stops. As there are no further state changes. You add a character again, same loop happens. It's not infinite.

You update the form, it updates the data which updates the form and that's it.